# JSDoc. Как правильно описать код для правильного перехода в IDE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

Как правильно описать код с помощью JSDoc? Например, у меня есть компонент базы данных

```
/**
     * A namespace.
     * @namespace components
     * @class Db
     */
    class Db {
      /**
       *
       * @param {Function} cb
       * @returns {*}
       */
      connect(cb) {

        return mongoose.connect(this.url, (err) => {
          cb()
         });
      }

    }
```

И есть IoC контейнер, который возвращает экземпляр этого класса:

```
/**
 * @type {components.Db}
 */    
let db = diContainer.resolve('db');
```

Но, при обращении к

```
db.connect()
```

IDE не видит функцию connect, т.е. моя IDE не хочет "прыгать" к классу Db.

Подскажите, как описать класс и переменную db, чтобы они были связаны с помощью JSDoc для IDE?

Пробовал в следующих IDE: WebStorm, PhpStorm.

Comment: а какая у вас IDE?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman PHPStorm

Comment: @MikhailVaysman пробовал и в WebStorm

Comment: добавьте это в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Для описания параметра типа функция, (метод  обратного вызова 'callback'), существует специальный тэг.

Как оформлять методы обратного вызова (callback) можно [почитать тут](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html#examples).

Пример кода, с использованием тэга @callback:

```
/**
 * Callback for adding two numbers.
 *
 * @callback addStuffCallback
 * @param {int} sum - An integer.
 */

/**
 * Add two numbers together, then pass the results to a callback function.
 *
 * @param {int} x - An integer.
 * @param {int} y - An integer.
 * @param {addStuffCallback} callback - A callback to run.
 */
function addStuff(x, y, callback) {
  callback(x+y);
}
```

Comment: _Вы просто не то в jsdoc используете. :)_ - стоит написать, что надо использовать

Comment: Так оно и написано :) @callback, и ссылка на официальную документацию + пример кода

Comment: а, не понял этого из ответа :)